# How to run 3 methods simultaneously or in parallel using java 8 Streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8

1) Keen to know how can we Run Method1 ,2,3 in parallel using Java 8

2) Is it the correct way to meet my requirements with java 8 using streams?

```
public void RunParallel()
{
    String method1 = method1();
    String method2 = method2();
    String method3 = method3(String Value);
}
```

`Stream.<Runnable>of(() -> method1(),() -> method2(),() -> method3()).parallel().forEach(Runnable::run);`

Comment: Create a Thread for each and call start() on them.

Comment: currently I am looking for java 8 version of it

Comment: @daniu "Creating a thread" Is almost always the wrong answer.  Prefer `Executor` to directly creating threads.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I meant this comment merely as a pointer for OP to do some Google research ;) But since we're on this topic, how are the `java.util.concurrent` helpers (eg `CyclicBarrier`) supposed to tie into the `Executor` concept? By providing a `ThreadFactory`? Or are those only meant for low-level cases where creating a Thread is appropriate?

Comment: @daniu They can be used together, with caveats.  Blocking inside a thread pool for which you don't control the thread-creation policy, or for which you don't know who else will use it, could lead to deadlock -- but if its your pool and you understand the policies, they can be safely used together.

Comment: I think the question is good. And the link to the "already answers" is wrong. But how to change this state?

Answer (score 13):

You can do the following with Java 8, with the following code method1, method2 & method3 run in parallel. If you want to do something after the completion of all then you can do with future.get();

```
public void RunParallel()
{
    CompletableFuture<Void> future1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        String method1 = method1();
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> future2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        String method2 = method2();
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> future3 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->{
        String method3 = method3("some inp");
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3); 
    try {
        future.get(); // this line waits for all to be completed
    } catch (InterruptedException  | ExecutionException e) {
        // Handle
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently the methods dont need to wait for each other

Comment: I have updated the description of my answer, please do check. With my solution, all the three methods run in parallel.

Comment: great.! thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Create Classes extending Thread for each different Method you want to run in parallel like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Operation1().start();
    new Operation2().start();
    ...
}

public class Operation1 extends Thread{
    public Operation1() {
        super("Operation1");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        method1();
    }
}
public class Operation2 extends Thread{
...
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating Thread classes, I find it much simpler to create Threads by giving the methods to the constructor, as in `new Thread(this::method1).start();`.

Comment: looking for Java 8 version for it

Comment: @daniu 's is a Java8 Version. The '::' version is more or less the same as mine but more compact. Daniu's variante just let the compiler generate the interface. Tahts much more shorter of course but only usefull for one Method

Comment: Even for Java 7, I found it better to create a class for each method implementing Runnable and passing it to new Thread, than have it extends Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way of  running methods in parallel

```
Thread thread1=new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       method1();
   }
};
thread1.start();
```

Repeat this for all your remaining methods.

Below is the sample code for you. Here all three threads, executing corresponding methods in parallel.

```
public class ThreadTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                method1();
            }
        };
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                method2();
            }
        };
        thread2.start();

        Thread thread3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                method3();
            }
        };
        thread3.start();

    }

    static void method1() {

        try {
            while(true){
            System.out.println("test1");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    static void method2() {
        try {
            while(true){
            System.out.println("test2");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    static void method3() {
        try {
            while(true){
            System.out.println("test3");
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: anything thing using java 8?

Comment: I will stick with java basics. Maybe something will  be in java8. Not sure. But I would like it keep it simple.